# Pivotal TC default website override

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I have Spring Tool Suite (3.9.2.RELEASE) which by default comes with the Pivotal TC web server, a variant on Apache Tomcat. From what I understand, in order to set the "default website" for Tomcat you modify the 'context' which points to your application. Best practices may say to define this in a different file, however I understand it is still possible to be done in 'server.xml'.

I have an application ("myApp") in STS. It is normally accessed via `http://localhost:8080/myApp`. I would like to access it at `http://localhost:8080` instead.

The following is a snip from the Pivotal TC 'server.xml'

```
<Context docBase="myApp" path="/myApp" ... />
```

I have modified this as follows, however I still reach the default Pivotal tc Server Runtime home page instead of my own:

```
<Context docBase="" path="/myApp"  ... />
```

Is there another location where I should be applying these changes to make them effective? There is obviously a something that I do not understand.

Many thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up [tomcat's documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html) for both attributes that you mention in your Context element, you'll find out:

docBase:

> The Document Base (also known as the Context Root) directory for this
>   web application, or the pathname to the web application archive file
>   (if this web application is being executed directly from the WAR
>   file). You may specify an absolute pathname for this directory or WAR
>   file, or a pathname that is relative to the appBase directory of the
>   owning Host.
>
> The value of this field must not be set unless the Context element is
>   defined in server.xml or the docBase is not located under the Host's
>   appBase...

path

> The context path of this web application, which is matched against the
>   beginning of each request URI to select the appropriate web
>   application for processing. All of the context paths within a
>   particular Host must be unique. If you specify a context path of an
>   empty string (""), you are defining the default web application for
>   this Host, which will process all requests not assigned to other
>   Contexts.
>
> This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in
>   server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from
>   the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase.
>
> Even when statically defining a Context in server.xml, this attribute
>   must not be set unless either the docBase is not located under the
>   Host's appBase or both deployOnStartup and autoDeploy are false. If
>   this rule is not followed, double deployment is likely to result.

In other words: You should modify the `path` attribute. When you do this, make sure to also undeploy the default content that would otherwise conflict with your own definition.

You'll also figure out that `""` is not a valid docBase, as it specifies a WAR file or a directory.